# Installation of the sqlite3-ruby gem fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

whenever I try to install the gem:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

I get the following output:

```
D:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=D:/Ruby/bin/ruby
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
--enable-local
--disable-local
```

I have properly installed sqlite3 on my Windows:

```
D:\>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

This is my second attempt of installation and again I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using ruby 2.x (currently beta and not working with sqlite3) instead of 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQLite first, so that you get the development headers required for the ruby gem to work.

Go to http://mislav.uniqpath.com/rails/install-sqlite3/#windows, and follow the instructions. Then the gem installation should succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Obviosly your error-message says "Install SQLite3 ... first."

try:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

please keep me informed if this solved your problem.

Comment: I get the same error message as in my first post when I type `gem install sqlite3`